# Read XML with XSD schema in java (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xsd

I am receiving a XML string from a webserver that contains a XSD schema-definition in the beginning looking like this:

```
...
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="" .../>
   <xs:element name="" .../>
   ...
</xs:sequence>

...
```

The attribute name defines the tags of a dataset in the xml part of the string that is underneath the schema-definition, looking like this:

```
...
<DataSet id="DataSet1">
   <name1>value</name1>
   <name2>value</name2>
   ...
</DataSet>
<DataSet id="DataSet2">
   <name1>value</name1>
   <name2>value</name2>
   ...
</DataSet>
...
```

Can someone give me an advice how to parse this.

PS: The number of elements defining the names is variable and can be different everytime so these tags are not static.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't just want to parse it, you also want to process it after parsing (unfortunately this misuse of the word "parse" is becoming endemic). Parsing should be trivial assuming that the file as a whole is well-formed XML (which you haven't said). Processing depends entirely on what you want to do with the data. For example, some kinds of processing might need the schema information, other kinds might not.